# Send HTTP 200 response from socket server

Tags: c

I am trying to send response to client, whenever I add `HTTP/1.1 200` to my buffer, the server wont start,whenever I go on localhost:18000 it loads forever. Without the http/1.1 200 it starts but I want to send a http response. Am I doing something wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int socket_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int port = 18000;
    char buffer[2000] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nHello";
    if (socket_server == -1)
    {
        return printf("Error in socket function");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addres;
    addres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addres.sin_port = htons(port);
    addres.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int bind_server = bind(socket_server, (struct sockaddr*) &addres, sizeof(addres)); 
    if(bind_server == -1) {
        return printf("Error in bind function");
    }

    int listens = listen(socket_server, 0);
    if(listens == -1) {
        return printf("Error in listen function");
    }

    for(;;) {
        int accepts = accept(socket_server, NULL, NULL);
        send(accepts, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nHello"` is not a valid http response.

Comment: What does "won't start" mean exactly? Does it crash? Does it get blocked in one of the system calls? You should be able to easily find out what the server is doing by running the program in a debugger or even just adding more debug print statements.

Comment: Also, you can't/shouldn't respond until you get a request.

Comment: Sending 20000 bytes doesn't seem right when the buffer only contains a small string.  Try `send(accepts, &buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);`  Also You probably want to close the accepts socket after sending.  And it wouldn't be a bad idea to check the return of accept for failure.